# sum nth row every loop

Tags: r

my objective is to sum every nth row by every count. Maybe a loop function might help.
I used this code :
 `irr = rollapply( irr , width = 1 , by = n , align = "left" , FUN = sum )`
Example:

```
 V1
3
2
4
7
5
```

so if `n = 2`, the first 2 rows will sum up.

Results:

```
V1
5
4
7
5
```

So the problem is, i have multiple "n" in another data.frame variable.
`2 5 3` and i want to make `"n"` change, let say to `"3"` when it finish summing the first two rows,
`next n = 3`
Results:

```
5 16
```

This is my first time using r so please pardon me for any mistake i made and if the question is hard to understand.Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have `dat = data.frame(V1 = c(3, 2, 4, 7, 5)); n = c(2, 3)`, you need `rowsum(dat, rep(seq_along(n), n))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split` the data frame according to `n` and then `sum` it over every list

As an example,

```
v1 <- data.frame(X = c(3,2,4,7,5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4))
n <- data.frame(Y = c(2, 3, 2, 4, 1,4))


unlist(lapply(split(v1$X, rep(1:nrow(n), n$Y)), sum))

# 1  2  3  4  5  6 
# 5 16  5 22  8 10
```

Comment: Hi, your method is exactly what i need! however i received an error message   Error in rep(1:nrow(n), n$Y) : invalid 'times' argument when i assigned X & Y to my list. i have 3516 obs. for X and 26 obs. for Y. any idea how to solve it? please let me know if you need more information thanks!

Comment: okay. So You have `v1` and `n` as data frame, right? and they have `X` and `Y` columns respectively ?

Comment: Yea that was the problem, thanks for replying so fast ! managed to get it to work now!